# Storing static data in react.js

Tags: reactjs, static

In my *react.js* application, I have `Login` class, which looks something like this :

```
class Login extends React.Component {

state={email:'',passwordHash:''};

onButtonClick = () =>{
    if(this.state.email==='' || this.state.passwordHash==='')
        return;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            if(request.responseText==="true")
            {
                window.location.href = '/home';
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.href='/bad_request';
            }
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/login/'+this.state.email+'/'+this.state.passwordHash, true);
    request.send();

};

...

}

export default Login;
```

Here I'm just receiving `true` or `false`, but I can bring change to my *REST API - Spring Boot* and make that return `User`, where all data about a user is stored.

I want that because, to do all things, first I need to identify that user.

**So my question is - How can I store that data for all of my class, like static or something?**

Comment: I think what you need is Redux, to store variables and data for all your application.

Also for login is not a good idea to use a get and place username and password in url, I would use post and JWT for the login system

Comment: I have studied about *Redux*  (only official doc and few videos). Can you please tell me, how to do it, in brief ?

Comment: I implemented this one in a small app and worked properly. It is a playlist that contains a lot of info about react login https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USaB1adUHM0

Comment: I am using **Spring Boot** in my backend. Sorry, I forget to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using `localStorage` to do this now.

`localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user)); // to store as string`

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')); // to retrieve as a json object`